# Error when importing certificate to Login keychain

Tags: mojave, keychain

I am trying to import a certificate into my Login keychain, using the Keychain Menu bar → File → Import items.... I navigate to the certificate, which is a .pfx file. It asks for my password and I type in the same one I use to get into my Mac.

I get 2 Popups - both with the header "An error has occurred. Unable to import an item". One show "OSStatus 2", and the other states "The contents of this item cannot be retrieved".

I am running macOS Majove 10.14.3 and using Google Chrome.

These certs were exported from a Windows machine and were emailed to me.

Comment: Possibly this? - https://superuser.com/questions/704692/cant-import-public-key-into-osx-keychain

Comment: Can you also try double clicking on the .pfx file and see if that makes any diff. when importing it.

Comment: using the command line did the trick - thank you slm

Comment: which method did you end up using from the SU Q&A?